# want to search from imdb database and need to save it to my db using rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save the imdb results to my db

this is what I am doing

```
@movie = @imdb.find_by_title(params[:search])
@movie = imdb.find_by_title("The Dark Knight")
```

it is even producing the results, which I want to save but since I am new to rails I am having lots of difficulties.

Comment: I am using imdb-party for searching the imdb api
and the result is as follows
I want to save each result in the database
how can I do that

Comment: You get the some hashes from IMDB, parse it and save into your models. As other option you could serialize it as string (in a form of xml or json).

Comment: As being newbie to rails things are piety much confusing , Can U Give a little example on it

Answer (score 0):

From [imdb-party](https://github.com/maddox/imdb-party/blob/master/lib/imdb_party/movie.rb) extract fields names:

```
  attr_accessor :imdb_id, :title, :directors, :writers, :tagline, :company, :plot, :runtime, :rating, :poster_url, :release_date, :certification, :genres, :actors, :trailers
```

Then you have two ways: 
1. Define the model in your app to store them (after just copying from `Movie` returned from IMDB)
2. Turn them into hash and save it as a string:

```
result_to_save = [:imdb_id, :title, :directors, :writers, :tagline, :company, :plot, :runtime, :rating, :poster_url, :release_date, :certification, :genres, :actors, :trailers].inject({}) do |r, k|
  r[k] = <insert_here_movie_instance>.send(k)
end
```